# How to know Proguard works properly in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I'm a new Proguard user  and I read number of articles about it.

As I understood, the name proguard.cfg is referring to the proguard-project.txt file. Am I correct or is there such a file called proguard.cfg?

The next thing what I want to know is how could I know proguard is working well for my project? I did not add any extra comments to proguard-project.txt. I saw in some postings they said that without using the command " -dontwarn android.support.** " in proguard-project.txt will give warnings. But I did not get any warning or any exceptions in my LogCat.

Where are those warnings/exceptions displaying at? What I need to know whether it is working well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the proguard configuration is in the **projects.properties** file.

> proguard.config=proguard-android-optimize.txt

So, whatever file you would specify here, the configurations will be picked up from that file.
I guess, the .cfg extension was being used earlier, and the documentations haven't been updated after they changed it to this file name inside android sdk tools.

> Proguard is working well?

Depends on how you are building your app. Eclipse doesn't generally show all the verbose warnings, may be a few, but not all.

So, if you are building with Eclipse, you just need to assume that it worked, unless eclipse fails creating a build, and then you would see a message. To confirm, either **decompile the APK**, or **run the app, while checking the logs**. If you can crash the app, and there's a stack trace, you can clearly see the method names are obfuscated.

If you want to see all the warnings for proguard during the build process, try building your app through ant. And in the console, you can see all the details (general + proguard) warnings also.

Comment: Thank you! In that case if there is any error does logcat display it?

Comment: Logcat no. You can see that in the console window.